# Trying to save changes to a SQL database, results in "Cannot open user default database. Login failed."

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am building an MVC application with C# as my language which is hosted on Widows 7 IIS. A call to Add a new member to the database works, but when attempting to save the change I get the following error:

Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\myApplication'

The SQL table was added just by adding it within VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user 'IIS APPPOOL\myApplication' has not been given access to the database which is defined as the default database for that user.

The bigger question is, what is your intended security access model? Pooled identity, connection per user, Impersonation?

Comment: To be honest, I do not rightly know, as I am new to web development. I was hoping for a lot of automagicness to save me by using VS2008. To give a little bit more background, user authentication is done via a connection to Active Directory. I am using an SQL database to try and keep track of previous entries users make to a form. User logs in, makes changes to form, form values get stored in SQL database, user logs out, logs back in at a later date, and the values are still there.